# Python polynomial curve fit with restricted output values

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, polynomials

I want to do a polynomial fit to some data using numpy in Python.  The data is saturated in the middle at 100%.  I would like the polynomial curve fit to be greater than 100% where the data is saturated.  The curve should not go below 100% in this range (+/-2.3 or so).  How can I restrict the output values to exceed a minimum (100%) value?
I am not able to use a piece-wise curve.  I need to fit a single polynomial curve.
Here is an example of the Python fitting:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x_data = np.array([4.69, 4.32, 3.94, 3.56, 3.17, 2.78, -2.78, -3.17, -3.55, -3.93, -4.31, -4.68])
y_data = np.array([72, 83, 91, 93, 94, 95, 99, 99, 98, 94, 85, 72])
coefficients = np.polyfit(x_data, y_data, 5)

x_eval = np.linspace(x_data.min(), x_data.max(), 1000)
y_eval = np.polyval(coefficients, x_eval)
plt.plot(x_data, y_data, 'o', label='Data')
plt.plot(x_eval, y_eval, label='Polynomial fit')

# Set the y-axis limits to be between 0 and 110.
plt.ylim(0, 110)

# Add a legend and title to the plot.
plt.legend()
plt.title('Polynomial fit to data')

# Display the plot.
plt.show()
```

You can see this curve fit drops below 100% in the center.
[image: Polynomial fit drops below 100% in the center where data is saturated at 100%]